# shell script grep regex in array

Tags: arrays, regex, shell, grep

I have this script where I print how many times an ip has failed to connect, and at what date this IP made its last try, it looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
searchString=$1
file=$2

countLines()
{
    declare -A ipCount
    declare -A lastDate

    cnt=0

    while read line;
    do
        ((cnt+=1))

        ipaddr=$( echo "$line" | grep -o -E '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' )

         lastDate[$ipaddr]=$( echo "$line" | grep -o -E '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\ [0-3][0-9]\ [0-2][0-9]\:[0-2][2-9]\:[0-2][2-9]' )

    ((ipCount[$ipaddr]+=1))
    done

    printf "%-18s %-10s %s\n" "IP" "Count" "lastDate"
    echo "-------------------------------------------------"

    for ip in ${!ipCount[*]}
    do
        printf "%-18s %-10s %s\n" "$ip" "${ipCount[$ip]}" "${lastDate[$ip]}"
    done | sort

    echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Count: $cnt"
    }

    grep "$searchString" $file | countLines
```

The file I try this on looks like this, but bigger

```
May 16 06:41:38 aprs sshd[25951]: Failed password for root from 137.241.229.226 port 2008 ssh2
May 16 06:41:40 aprs sshd[25951]: Failed password for root from 137.241.229.226 port 2008 ssh2
May 16 06:41:43 aprs sshd[25951]: Failed password for root from 37.141.229.226 port 2008 ssh2
May 16 06:41:46 aprs sshd[25951]: Failed password for root from 37.141.229.226 port 2008 ssh2
May 16 06:41:48 aprs sshd[25951]: Failed password for root from 37.141.229.226 port 2008 ssh2
```

and what I get is this

```
IP                 Tries      LastDate
-----------------------------------------------
37.141.229.226     205        
137.241.229.226    705        May 16 07:08:24
-----------------------------------------------
Count: 910
```

As you can see, I only get 'lastDate' on one of the IP's, this also happens on the big log file, I guess it's really simple, but I can't find out why, can you help me?

I run the script like: bash scriptname.sh "Failed password for root" logFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be in the regex for `lastDate`.  Replace:

```
lastDate[$ipaddr]=$( echo "$line" | grep -o -E '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\ [0-3][0-9]\ [0-2][0-9]\:[0-2][2-9]\:[0-2][2-9]' )
```

with:

```
lastDate[$ipaddr]=$( echo "$line" | grep -o -E '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] [0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' )
```

The key part was the match for hour:minute:second.  The original had `[0-2][0-9]\:[0-2][2-9]\:[0-2][2-9]`.  This restricts the match to times from the top of the hour to half past and also restricts the match to only the first half of each minute.  The more general replacement is `0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`

Also, spaces and colons are not active characters for `grep`.  Consequently, they do not need to be escaped.